# Python script showing ModuleNotFoundError when starting script through automated SSH

Tags: python, windows, amazon-ec2, ssh, gitlab

So this is driving me crazy, I can't seem to find a solution to my problem through the hours of researching and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I'm using terraform to spin up a Windows Server 2019 EC2 instance which a Alpine (Linux) GitLab runner then SSH's into to execute some python scripts. In the powershell userdata I'm installing python3 through chocolately and using py -m pip requests,...,.. to install all the modules. Up to this point everything is installed properly as I've looked at the EC2 log file. Now the GitLab runner starts to SSH into the EC2 instance to run the python scripts using "py script.py argument1 argument2 argument3". At this point I get a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'. This error does not occur when I however manually SSH from my laptop to the EC2 instance and run "py script.py argument1 argument2 argument3", the scripts run perfectly how they should. It's only when the GitLab runner is using SSH it gets the error.

I've tried everything from, using the file path "C:\Python39\python.exe" instead of "py" to launch the scripts, to adjusting the %PATH% and %PYTHONPATH% variables. When checking sys.path however, the Lib/site-packages directory is there which is where the modules are installed.

I'm not sure why when the runner uses SSH to run the scripts it shows this error but when manually SSHing from my mac it does not. I read that after python3.3, Python also installs py which may be the issue? However when I run the scripts with "C:\Python39\python.exe" it should be getting the packages from site-packages like it does when manually SSHing.

Any help is useful, thanks!